# Creating a boxplot showing the spread of gene-expression within different samples

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

So I have a dataframe containing the 10 most upregulated genes in cancer-samples compared to control-samples and the 10 most downregulated genes.
It looks like this:

[image: Initial dataframe:]

I want to create a neat boxplot to compare the spread of each gene between patient-samples and control-samples (there are 4 samples of each type).

The problems I have is that I don't get all boxes along-side each other in a row/in the same graph, but like this:

[image: Boxplot output]

I would also like it to show the gene's boxes sorted by the "log2FC-value", and not be in alphabetical order. Does anyone know how to fix this??

This is my code I used:

```r
#Im using the dataframe called "Dataframe"


#Make a column for the genenames 
Dataframe$genenames <- rownames(Dataframe)


#Get data into a long-format
long_Dataframe <- gather(Dataframe, key="samples", 
            value="values", -c(log2FC, gennames,))

#Creating a new column called "group", stating if each row belongs to patient/control
long_Dataframe$group <- rep(c("Control", "Patient"), each=40)

#Order rows by log2FC - from lowest to highest
long_Dataframe <- long_Dataframe[order(long_Dataframe$log2FC), , 
                  drop=FALSE]

#Use long data for boxplot of top 20 up/downregulated genes
Boxplot_top20 <- ggplot(long_Dataframe, aes(x=genenames, y=values, fill=group)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("green", "red")) +
  theme_light() +
  facet_wrap(~genenames, scales="free")
```

Comment: Add `Dataframe$genenames <- fct_reorder(Dataframe$genenames, Dataframe$log2FC)`

Comment: Thank you!! It fixed the alphabetical ordering problem. So now I only need to make the bars appear within the same plot, alongside eachother, do you happen to know how to fix that?

Comment: If you want all genes in the same plot, don't use `facet_wrap()`

Comment: Ok so, I deleted it! But I still think the graph looks a bit messy.. Is there maybe a way to put all genes within the same graph but the 10 ones with highest log2FC on the top, then the lowest 10 on a row underneath the others?

Or is it not possible?

I also think it would look neater to grade the y-axis perhaps, to put in more values on it

Comment: I dont think I can insert a picture of it anymore, but the bars are quite thin and squished together, since there's so many on the same row with not that much space in between

Answer (score 0):

You may use `geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge())` instead of `facet_wrap()` to place your boxplots by pair within group.

Comment: Thank you! The graph still looks a bit messy though..since there's so many bars they looked squished together with little space in between. Do you know if there's a way to put the 10 genes with highest log2FC-value on the top, and the rest on like a row underneath, but with all of them still in the same graph?

Comment: I think the way is to create new group where you divide genes by expression to High and Low and use `facet_wrap()` for the group with arguments ncol = 1 to place your groups one on top of other.

Comment: ohh, so something like this? long_Dataframe$group2 <- , but how would I divide the samples into "high" or "low"? So all positive log2FC-values are "high" and negative "low" (Im still extremely new to R, and we're still going through basics in my course)

Comment: I would suggest to create new group before melting `library(dplyr)
df<- df %>% 
  mutate(group = if_else(log2FC < 1, "Down", "Up"))` and then melt data with the group. And finally use `facet_wrap( ~ group, ncol= 1)` to divide plot.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It now looks like this:  https://tinypic.host/i/boxplot3.R79k5   ,   It's not possible to have the boxes under eachother though is it? To get the genenames under respective rows :)

Comment: Yeah, honestly I thought it will place them under each other. I don't know, maybe `facet_wrap(scales = free_x)` will help...

Comment: @Lina Is your `genenames` variable a factor? Try converting it with `as.character()` to avoid all gene names appearing in both groups.